# Cycling through background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this question has been asked many times ago, but please, give it a try, and read it to the end.

So, I am trying to make my HTML page a bit more...active. I want to change the background image every 5 seconds or so with a simple fade animation. For example, I could have:

```
+ BackgroundImages \
|---- 1.png
|---- 2.png
|---- 3.png
|---- 4.png
```

I want to create a javascript (jQuery) script that is able to cycle through all the images in that folder and change the background image accordingly every 5 seconds or so.

**What have I tried so far?** I've seen many result on Google, but they seem to have no logic (like the `jQuery.cycle()`) they use much markup (and I want to avoid that).

So, please, provide me with a less-markup solution, something simple to solve my little problem.

Comment: Are you creating a div for each background image? Or are you making the background image a CSS property of 'body'? Or are you expecting someone to write the code for you?

Comment: My idea was to make the background image a CSS property, but I don't know what to do then, so I need somebody to write (at least a part of it) for me.

Comment: What is it about the markup that you want to avoid? Many cycle plugins rely fairly heavily on the markup and CSS.

Comment: Are you wanting to learn how to write this or just find something simple? If you want something simple try this - http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: @JayBlanchard, it looks promising! Please, write an answer about this, and I will accept it!

Comment: Done @Victor - I hope that it works well for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something simple for background cycling images I would use http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

*I know that this is a link only answer, but please see OP's comments about posting this.*

Comment: It is what I need, I found an example on the page you linked to! Thank you!